# I can't clone on gitlab with ssh

Tags: gitlab

I can clone over https just fine but after I connect my ssh key, I keep getting the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host gitlab.example.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried deleting and recreating the ssh key and adjusting the config port to 443 and nothing has worked.

Comment: Is it a self-hosted GitLab?

Comment: Someone else hosts the repo

Comment: You may check your settings at `~/.ssh/config` and confirm it's what you want.

Comment: The only thing I have in my config is:

Host *
 UseKeychain yes

Am I supposed to have something else?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an on-premise GitLab installation (meaning *not* gitlab.com), chances are port 22 is should not be blocked.

Double-check that with:

```
curl -v telnet://gitlab.example.com:22
```

Switching to 443 would rather involve HTTPS. (github.com does have an SSH listener on port 443 or ssh.github.com, but that is probably not the case for your own GitLab  server), [unless your server is configured to do so on `altssh.gitlab.example.com`](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/02/18/gitlab-dot-com-now-supports-an-alternate-git-plus-ssh-port/).